# How do I print a specific part of a YAML string

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

My YAML database:

```
left:
  - title: Active Indicative
    fill: "#cb202c"
    groups:
      - "Present | dūc[ō] | dūc[is] | dūc[it] | dūc[imus] | dūc[itis] | dūc[unt]"
```

My Python code:

```
import io
import yaml

with open("C:/Users/colin/Desktop/LBot/latin3_2.yaml", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
txt = doc["left"][1]["groups"][1]
print(txt)
```

Currently my output is `Present | dūc[ō] | dūc[is] | dūc[it] | dūc[imus] | dūc[itis] | dūc[unt]` but I would like the output to be `ō`, `is`, `it`, or `imus`. Is this possible in PyYaml and if so how would I implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about extracting the text inside `[ ]` from `txt`?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: There's nothing at all about this that's specific to YAML -- after all, you're already extracting the string you want to break into pieces from the larger structure; it's a single string in YAML, so making that into a single string in Python is as far as the YAML parser's responsibility goes. If you just took the string `'Present | dūc[ō] | dūc[is] | dūc[it] | dūc[imus] | dūc[itis] | dūc[unt]'` as your input and left the YAML parts out of the question entirely, you'd still have the exact same problem (but with fewer unrelated/complicating factors mixed in).

Comment: ...on which point, note the [mre] guidelines -- we do ask for *minimal* questions, simplified as far as possible while still allowing reproduction and testing of the issue at hand.

Comment: ...that said, are you sure you want `[1]`s rather than `[0]`s when indexing? Keep in mind that `[1]` is the *second* element in a list; `[0]` is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a PyYaml solution, but if you already have the string from the YAML file, you can use Python's [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to extract the text inside the `[ ]`.

```py
import re

txt = "Present | dūc[ō] | dūc[is] | dūc[it] | dūc[imus] | dūc[itis] | dūc[unt]"

parts = txt.split(" | ")
print(parts)  
# ['Present', 'dūc[ō]', 'dūc[is]', 'dūc[it]', 'dūc[imus]', 'dūc[itis]', 'dūc[unt]']

pattern = re.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]")
output = []
for part in parts:
    match = pattern.search(part)
    if match:
        # group(0) is the matched part, ex. [ō]
        # group(1) is the text inside the (.*?), ex. ō
        output.append(match.group(1))
    else:
        output.append(part)

print(" | ".join(output))
# Present | ō | is | it | imus | itis | unt
```

The code first splits the text into individual parts, then loops through each part [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search)-ing for the pattern `[x]`. If it finds it, it extracts the text inside the brackets from the [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) and stores it in a list. If the `part` does not match the pattern (ex. `'Present'`), it just adds it as is.

At the end, all the extracted strings are [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)-ed together to re-build the string without the brackets.

---

**EDIT** based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084411/how-do-i-print-a-specific-part-of-a-yaml-string/58089613#comment102591022_58089613):

If you just need one of the strings inside the `[ ]`, you can use the same regex pattern but use the [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method instead on the entire `txt`, which will return a `list` of matching strings *in the same order that they were found*.

```py
import re

txt = "Present | dūc[ō] | dūc[is] | dūc[it] | dūc[imus] | dūc[itis] | dūc[unt]"

pattern = re.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]")
matches = pattern.findall(txt)
print(matches) 
# ['ō', 'is', 'it', 'imus', 'itis', 'unt']
```

Then it's just a matter of using some variable to select an item from the list:

```py
selected_idx = 1  # 0-based indexing so this means the 2nd character
print(matches[selected_idx])
# is
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How would I implement this so that the output is only `ō` or `is`?

Comment: Clarification: How would I implement this so that I can choose whether I want the first option `ō` or the second option `is`?

Comment: It's still not clear. What is the expected string output? Just `ō` or `is`? If you're using my answer, you could `break` out of the loop once you've find the 1st matching pattern.

Comment: So if a variable == 1 then the output will be `o` but if the variable == 2 then the output will be `is`

Comment: @ColinMiller I edited my answer to show how to select a select a particular `[x]`.